# Javafx tableview column header

Tags: java, javafx

I use font size to zoom data view when I increase font the size column header height increase in the right way but when reset font size column header height don't decreased how can I fix that , I am use java fx u40

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not just a refresh problem.
One way of checking this is:

```
yourTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
yourTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```